# Are there standards for how one should typeset in (La)TeX a scientific paper?

Tags: typography

I'm looking for publications from people who have studied about this and give out rules, advice, orientation regarding how to (in general) present a writing.  I'd like publications such as books or journal articles, not university web pages laying out rules.  (Although, if the person is an expert, I'll definitely like to check her/his opinions.)

I'm not concerned with the overall design of the publication: each journal, each university, each organization will demand its own, period.

I'm looking for justified guidelines.

At this very moment, I'm particularly interested in seeing arguments for how one should cite references --- how to lay out punctuation and references, whether to put the author name in parentheses, year, whether to use numbers or letters in brackets and so on.

For example, should references by written with a space before punctuation [1]?  Or no, they should not[2].

In a lecture I watched, I was told references should be written as if when removed the text would still be perfectly laid out and sensible.  So one should not write "see [3] for more information" because removing the reference yields "see for more information."

This sounds ridiculous until I can find a real case where removing a reference would actually be a real-world situation.  Nevertheless, this rule is nice in the sense that's an easy to understand rule and abstracts all cases.  (I like the mathematical nature of that.)

Comment: The style of the references is normally dictated by the publication venue as well. About the only thing you need to worry about is the placement of `\cite` in the text and the structure of a sentence with a `\cite` in it. But that is not really a technical question but  probably one for https://academia.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is really off topic for the site. It has nothing to do with TeX really, and is also heavily opinion based. There are almost as many citation/bibliography schemes as there are journals.  Bringhurst's *The Elements of Typographic Style* is one major version of what good typography should be.  More specifically TeX related, the author of the `memoir` class also has [A Few Notes on Book Design](http://texdoc.net/pkg/memdesign.pdf).

Comment: Regarding removing references, you would write something like "see Awinita et.al. [3] for more information."  But you don't appear to actually have a TeX question, unless you completely rewrite it as "how can I write `\cite{awinita}` so that it's placement in the text and the structure of its sentence can change according to the requirements of journals A and B?"